# Variable de respuesta despues de hacer un update en un stored procedure sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente SP :

```
USE [gestionriesgo]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[SpCambioPass] 
@userLogin varchar(30),
@pass varchar(80),
@salt varchar(80)
as
begin
update userRegister
set pass = @pass, salt = @salt
where userLogin = @userLogin 
end
```

y si afecta a mas de una fila me devuelva una variable que diga `exitoso` de lo contrario que diga `Error al actualizar`, pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Después del `UPDATE` puedes obtener las filas afectadas en la operación mediante la función del sistema `@@ROWCOUNT`. Si esta es superior a cero devuelves "exitoso", de otra forma "error".

Pongo la parte relevante del código

```
update userRegister
set pass = @pass, salt = @salt
where userLogin = @userLogin 

select case @@ROWCOUNT 
   when > 0 then 'exitoso' 
   else 'Error al actualizar' 
end as Respuesta
```